# Can anyone suggest a quick triangle detection algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, math, geometry, lines

I have some data in the form of Line objects (eg Line1(start, end), where start and end are coordinates in the form of point objects). Is there a quick way to go through all the lines to see if any of them form a triangle? By quick I mean anything better than going through all nC3 possibilities.

Edit: Just realised I may not understand all the replies (I'm no Adrian Lamo). Please try and explain wrt Python.

Comment: Can there be endpoints shared by more than two segments ?

Comment: No. I'm assuming no two lines share the same endpoint pair.

Comment: You didn't answer my question. If no segment share an endpoint, there can be no triangle !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) geometric step: enter all line segments in a dictionary, with the first endpoint as the key and the second endpoint as the value. There will be duplicate keys, so you will keep a list of values rather than single values. In principle there will be no duplicates in the lists (unless you enter the same edge twice).

2) topological step: for all entries `P` in the dictionary, consider all the pairs of elements from its list, let `(Q, R)`. Lookup `Q` and check if `R` belongs to the list of `Q`. If yes, you have found the triangle `(P, Q, R)`.

By symmetry, all six permutations of every triangle will be reported. You can avoid that by enforcing that `P<Q<R` in the lexicographical sense.

Comment: Just an afterthought, will this be more efficient than going through all possible line triplets? Because traversing the dictionary requires a loop and identifying all `(Q, R)` pairs is another two loops.

Comment: No, the pairs (P, Q) are from sublists, in principle very short. I cannot tell you more as you didn't answer my question.

Comment: Alright, that's good for me. Also, about segments sharing endpoints, two or more segments may meet at a single point but no two segments have the same starting point and ending point. In other words, a point may have many line segments emerging from it but no two segments coincide, much like a simple graph. Hope this clarifies your question. Again, thanks a lot!

Comment: Then the algorithm is still valid but if all segments originate from the same endpoint, it will degenerate to O(N³). If this occurs, you can reduce the complexity by sorting the other endpoints in increasing angles, so that there are only O(N) potential triangles instead of O(N²). Due to the sort, the total complexity drops to O(N²Log(N)).

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a quick way to go through all the lines to see if any of them form a triangle?

Yes. Assuming that your Points are integers (or can be easily converted to such, because they have fixed significant digits or similar):

Being creative for you here:

1. Make two fastly searchable storage structures (e.g. `std::multimap<int>`), one for each of the x and y coordinates of the endpoints, associating the coordinates with a pointer to the respective line
2. In the first structure, search for elements with the same x coordinate. Those are the only "candidates" for being a corner of a triangle. Searching for duplicate entries is fast, because of you using an appropriate data structure.
3. For each of these, verify whether they are actually an edge. If they are not, discard.
4. For each of the remaining corners, verify that both "opposite" line ends are part of the same edge. Discard the others. Done.

Comment: Hey, I appreciate the quick answer. However, I'm having a bit of trouble comprehending it (I'm sorry, that's totally me being a bit dumb). Could you reword it for Python?

Comment: um, that applies to python, too. I can't write your code here. It would just take too long, and you don't want to pay my consulting rates ;)